# Why is my field not showing up when I add blur script?

Tags: javascript

I want the field to show Click here to add items*** and when the field is clicked on, the text to disappear. However, when I add the blur script, the text does not show at all?

```
//On Focus Script:
if (event.target.value == event.target.defaultValue) {
    event.target.value = "Click here to add items***";
}

//On Blur Script:
if (event.target.value == "Click here to add items***") {
    event.target.value = event.target.defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the related markup and event bindings that these lines are within? Or, possibly create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? – One possibility is that it seems you may have the events reversed. – Though, if this is for an `<input>`, are you familiar with the [`placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder)?

Comment: It seems like you have it backwards. When they focus on the field you want to remove the "Click here" text, and when they blur you want to add it back.

Answer (score 1):

You can use placeholder to do this effect:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Click here to add items***"><br>
```